# Custom Widget Disabled / Greyed out in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I followed this tutorial to create my own Widget: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/

Everything is fine but... My Widget doesn't appear in the webpage and is greyed out in the admin panel

[image: description]

Any idea?

EDIT

Test.php (plugins/test)

```
<?php
    /**
     * Plugin Name: Test
     * Plugin URI: http://www.test.com
     * Description: This is a test plugins
     * Version: 0.0.1
     * Author: Doe
     * Author URI: http://www.test.com
     * License: GPL2
     */

    include 'settings.php';
    include 'widget.php';

    if( is_admin() )
        $settings = new TestSettings();
?>
```

widget.php

```
<?php 
    class test_widget extends WP_Widget {

        // constructor
        function test_widget() {
            $widget_ops = array( 
                'class_name' => 'test_widget',
                'description' => 'MyWidget',
            );
            parent::__construct( 'test_widget', 'MyWidget', $widget_ops );
        }

        // widget form creation
        function form($instance) {  
            $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
            ?>
            <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
            </p>
            <?php 
        }

        // widget update
        function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
              $instance = $old_instance;
              // Fields
              $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
             return $instance;
        }

        // widget display
        function widget($args, $instance) {
            echo "Is there anybody out there?";
        }
    }
?>
```

settings.php

```
<?php 
    class TestSettings
    {
        /**
         * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
         */
        private $options;

        /**
         * Start up
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
            add_action( 'widgets_init', array( $this, 'register_widget' ) );
        }


        public function register_widget() {
            register_widget( 'test_widget' );
        }

        /**
         * Add options page
         */
        public function add_plugin_page()
        {
            // This page will be under "Settings"
            add_options_page(
                'Settings Admin', 
                'Test', 
                'manage_options', 
                'test', 
                array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
            );
        }

        /**
         * Options page callback
         */
        public function create_admin_page()
        {
            // Set class property
            $this->options = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
            ?>
            <div class="wrap">
                <form method="post" action="options.php">
                    <?php settings_fields( 'test-settings-group' ); ?>
                    <?php do_settings_sections( 'test-settings-group' ); ?>
                    <table class="form-table">
                        <tr valign="top">
                        <th scope="row">Fournisseur</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="provider" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('provider') ); ?>" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr valign="top">
                        <th scope="row">Script</th>
                            <td><textarea name="script" rows="10" style="width:100%;"><?php echo esc_attr( get_option('script') ); ?></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <?php submit_button(); ?>
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

        /**
         * Register and add settings
         */
        public function page_init()
        {        
            register_setting( 'test-settings-group', 'provider' );     
            register_setting( 'test-settings-group', 'script' );     
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide your code?

Comment: @James: Thanks, i've added the code :)

Comment: The code `?>
            <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
            </p>
            <?php 
        }` is strange and mix html and php in your function. Sorry, but I can't understand it. Do you have any error in your error.log? Maybe it helps!

Comment: @james: Yeah, it's just for my test, in the end it will be on a separated file. It's just to display a field named "title" and its label in the theme's customization page, it's not realy important here.

I'ven't any error on the page or you mean in a wordpress log file?

Comment: I was talking about the PHP error log (commonly in /var/log/apache2/error.log if you are using Apache with Linux). I'm asking for it because I don't see anything wrong in your code, so I'm not able to help you with it :-(